# How to correctly type the VueUse useFirestore() wrapper?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vueuse

I am using this [useFirestore()](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/) wrapper provided by VueUse.org

And I'm trying to type the `user` ref it returns with `User`, like this:

```TypeScript
import { User } from 'src/types';
const userId = useUserStore().user.id;
const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userId);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef); // <-- Error shows here
```

And this is what my `User` interface looks like:

```TypeScript
export interface User {
  id: string;
  userType?: UserType;
  createdAt?: Timestamp;
  email?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  initials?: string;
  passwordUpdatedAt?: Timestamp;
  photoUrl?: string;
  phoneE164Format?: string;
  phoneNationalFormat?: string;
  stripeId?: string;
  stripeLink?: string;
  googleTokens?: {
    access_token: string;
    expiry_date: number;
    id_token: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    token_type: string;
  };
}
```

This works. The `user` variable now has intellisense with `User` properties.

But it also produces this error on `userDocRef`:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(maybeDocRef:
> MaybeRef<DocumentReference>, initialValue?: User | undefined,
> options?: UseFirestoreOptions | undefined): Ref<...>', gave the
> following error.   Overload 2 of 4, '(maybeDocRef:
> MaybeRef<Query>, initialValue?: User[] | undefined, options?:
> UseFirestoreOptions | undefined): Ref<...>', gave the following
> error.ts(2769)

At the [bottom of the useFirestore() docs](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/) it has a section named "Type Declarations" which might help. But it is hard for me to fully understand.

I think I am doing the correct thing by passing `User` as a generic. So I am not sure why I get this error.

Why am I seeing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

My interface had a required `id` property that was causing a conflict.

Here is the full final code:

```TypeScript
const userId = useUserStore().user.id;
const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userId);
const user = useFirestore<User>(userDocRef);
```

```TypeScript
export interface User {
  id?: string;  // <-- Updated here
  userType?: UserType;
  createdAt?: Timestamp;
  email?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  initials?: string;
  passwordUpdatedAt?: Timestamp;
  photoUrl?: string;
  phoneE164Format?: string;
  phoneNationalFormat?: string;
  stripeId?: string;
  stripeLink?: string;
  googleTokens?: {
    access_token: string;
    expiry_date: number;
    id_token: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    token_type: string;
  };
}
```

This answers the question and fixes my immediate problem, but I'm not sure why I need all interface properties to be optional. That seems quite restrictive.

If anyone knows why please comment below.